# Jest beforeAll vs beforeEach unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a quite simple test, basically I'm trying to mock i18next's t function:

```
import { t } from 'i18next';
import { changeDocumentTitle } from './utils';

jest.mock('i18next');

const tMock = (key: string): string => key;

beforeAll(() => {
  (t as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(tMock);
});

test('test changeDocumentTitle function', () => {
  changeDocumentTitle('string');
  expect(document.title).toEqual(tMock('string'));
});
```

and the `changeDocumentTitle` implementation:

```
import { t } from 'i18next';

export const changeDocumentTitle = (titleKey: string): void => {
  document.title = t(`${titleKey}`);
};
```

Unfortunately, the test fails. But if I change it from `beforeAll` to `beforeEach`, everything's fine. How is that? Why `beforeAll` is not applying my mock unlike `beforeEach`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. The test case passed. See example https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/stackoverflow/71774180

Comment: @slideshowp2 thank you for your help, I re-checked everything on my side, unfortunately the problem is still here, maybe it is something with CRA default jest config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since react-scripts v4 it added the default jest config `resetMocks: true`: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.0

This means that the mocks are being reset before the tests runs with `beforeAll`. I recommended keeping `resetMocks: true`, because tests should be isolated.